# What happens when we make fetch="join" and lazy="true" in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join

If we use fetching strategy as "join", a single join query is fired (combining parent and children through one join query) and the default behavior is equivalent to lazy="false". This means that all the children records would be fetched for the parent at once. But, what would be the behavior, if we mark lazy="true"? Since the join query is single, what would be lazily fetched?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FetchMode Join overrides the lazy property. It will simple be ignored.
Should you be interested in a detailed explanation about Fetchmodes, take a look [here](http://www.solidsyntax.be/lessons-learned/hibernate-fetchmode-explained-example/). The article describes the Hibernate fetchmodes and the output which they produce.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the article link is not opening up ... any substitute...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your article is also very good. I have tweeted your article. Thanks for helping to understand different fetchmodes with nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

> With fetch="join" on a collection or single-valued association
>   mapping, you will actually avoid the second SELECT (hence making the
>   association or collection non-lazy), by using just one "bigger" outer
>   (for nullable many-to-one foreign keys and collections) or inner (for
>   not-null many-to-one foreign keys) join SELECT to get both the owning
>   entity and the referenced entity or collection. If you use
>   fetch="join" for more than one collection role for a particular entity
>   instance (in "parallel"), you create a Cartesian product (also called
>   cross join) and two (lazy or non-lazy) SELECT would probably be
>   faster.
>
> Use lazy="true" on , and  mappings to enable lazy
>   loading of individual scalar value-typed properties (a somewhat exotic
>   case). Requires bytecode instrumentation of compiled persistent
>   classes for the injection of interception code. Can be overriden in
>   HQL with FETCH ALL PROPERTIES.

From https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies. 
Hope it help